# OpenGL ES in another thread is not drawing on physical device

Tags: iphone, opengl-es

I have put my OpenGL ES initialization in another thread with CAEAGLLayer.

```
    context = [[EAGLContext alloc] initWithAPI:kEAGLRenderingAPIOpenGLES1 sharegroup:group];        
if (!context || ![EAGLContext setCurrentContext:context])
{
    [self release];
}

// Create system framebuffer object. The backing will be allocated in -reshapeFramebuffer
glGenFramebuffersOES(1, &viewFramebuffer);
glGenRenderbuffersOES(1, &viewRenderbuffer);
glBindFramebufferOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES, viewFramebuffer);
glBindRenderbufferOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, viewRenderbuffer);
[context renderbufferStorage:GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES fromDrawable:eaglLayer];
glFramebufferRenderbufferOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0_OES, GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, viewRenderbuffer);
```

and then draw it to screen

```
    BOOL rel = [EAGLContext setCurrentContext:context];
drawPixels(backingWidth, backingHeight, framebuf1, texID);
rel = [context presentRenderbuffer:GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES];
```

the buffer is displaying in simulator, but on a device, all I get is a black screen. 
do I need to configure something else?

Comment: Find a solution? I'm having the same problem where it works great in simulator but nothing shows on the device.

Answer (score 2):

OpenGL contexts can be active in only one thread on a time. So you've first to detach the context from one thread and reattach it in another one. It looks like your code lacks the detaching.

Comment: i assume he means [EAGLContext setCurrentContext:nil]; to detach